# programa que muestre los valores de las siguientes monedas,el problema,que no tiene que aceptar numeros negativos en el textbox de cantidad

Tags: visual-studio

```
Dim c = txtCantidad.Text
        If cboMoneda.SelectedItem = "" Or txtMoneda.Text = "" And txtCantidad.Text = "" Then
        End If
        If (cboMoneda.SelectedItem = "Dolar") Then
            lblIgual.Text = Val(txtCantidad.Text) & " Dolar equivale a " & Val(txtCantidad.Text) * Val(txtMoneda.Text) & " pesos"
            If c <= 0 Then
                txtMoneda.Text = "El valor no puede ser negativo"
            End If
        End If
        If (cboMoneda.SelectedItem = "Euro") Then
            lblIgual.Text = Val(txtCantidad.Text) & " Euro equivale a " & Val(txtCantidad.Text) * Val(txtMoneda.Text) & " pesos"
            If c <= 0 Then
                txtMoneda.Text = "El valor no puede ser negativo"
            End If
        End If
        If (cboMoneda.SelectedItem = "Yen") Then
            lblIgual.Text = Val(txtCantidad.Text) & " Yen equivale a " & Val(txtCantidad.Text) * Val(txtMoneda.Text) & " pesos"
            If c <= 0 Then
                txtMoneda.Text = "El valor no puede ser negativo"
            End If
        End If
```

Comment: Mírate el tour para nuevos usuarios, sobre todo cómo hacer buenas preguntas, claras y concisas. Y por favor utiliza mayúsculas...

Answer (score 0):

Comprueba con otro If si la moneda es mayor que 0 y anidas los demas dentro del primero...

```html
Dim c = txtCantidad.Text
        If cboMoneda.SelectedItem = "" Or _
        txtMoneda.Text = "" And _
        txtCantidad.Text = "" Then
        End If
        If txtCantidad.Text > 0 Then
           If (cboMoneda.SelectedItem = "Dolar") Then
              lblIgual.Text = Val(txtCantidad.Text) & " Dolar equivale a " & Val(txtCantidad.Text) * Val(txtMoneda.Text) & " pesos"
              If c <= 0 Then
                  txtMoneda.Text = "El valor no puede ser negativo"
              End If
            End If
          If (cboMoneda.SelectedItem = "Euro") Then
              lblIgual.Text = Val(txtCantidad.Text) & " Euro equivale a " & Val(txtCantidad.Text) * Val(txtMoneda.Text) & " pesos"
              If c <= 0 Then
                txtMoneda.Text = "El valor no puede ser negativo"
              End If
          End If
          If (cboMoneda.SelectedItem = "Yen") Then
              lblIgual.Text = Val(txtCantidad.Text) & " Yen equivale a " & Val(txtCantidad.Text) * Val(txtMoneda.Text) & " pesos"
              If c <= 0 Then
                  txtMoneda.Text = "El valor no puede ser negativo"
              End If
          End If
      End If
```